# Changing PhD supervisor 18 months into 4 year PhD

Tags: soft-question

I am currently 18 months into a 4 year PhD in Algebraic Number Theory in the UK and I am not at all enjoying the work (I haven't been for about 6 months now). This is not because I am "stuck" - I am not really at a point where I have been able to engage enough with the work to even become stuck. The problem is more motivational: it turns out that I just don't have any interest in my particular area and so I spend most of my time either worrying about working or worrying whilst working - very inefficient! The area in which I work is also quite small in the sense that very few (in fact, only one that is comprehensive - as far as I am aware) textbooks have been written on the basics and even my supervisor admits that these few books are exceedingly dry.

With all this in mind, I decided recently that I will leave the PhD and do something else (I actually have no idea what yet). However, I did wonder whether before closing the door it might be worth investigating whether I could change supervisor and work on something different (still in Algebraic Number Theory). I guess my question is whether others on this site (PhD students or PhD supervisors) have had a similar experience or have any advice regarding this situation?

**Note.** I have no doubt that this post will almost instantly be marked as "off-topic" - however I really think that it is difficult to obtain the opinions of professional mathematicians on other forums whereas (quite often) they respond to questions of this type on this site.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you should speak to your advisor.  A reasonable PhD advisor wants their students to enjoy the subfield they are working in and will be happy to either suggest alternate directions or arrange a change of advisor if necessary.  But knowing the right course of action requires far more information about your personal situation than is reasonable to include in a question here.  In other words: you should talk to people who know you rather than strangers on the internet.

Comment: This question is more suited to academia.stackexchange.  I do not recommend the Internet over talking to people over concerns such as yours, but if you do twenty minutes of good web searching, I imagine a question very much like yours has been asked in different fora at least ten times before.  These question askers are the people whose advice you might value.  (Also, there is a reason your advisor is called an advisor.) Gerhard "Certainly Start With Internet Search" Paseman, 2017.10.30.

Comment: Consider to ask this on https://academia.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: As I understand it, you like algebraic number theory but not the particular sub-area that you're working in. If your relationship with your supervisor is good and if (s)he is not too super-specialized in one sub-area, you might be able to just move to a different sub-area while continuing to work with the same supervisor. That might be administratively simpler than finding a new supervisor.

Comment: What would you want your advisor to say about you?  E.g.: a) “X couldn’t hack it in my area of number theory”; b) “X thought it would be more fun to do research in a more computational/group-theoretical/geometric vein”; c) “X decided to leave academia and told me about some neat careers I never knew about.”  With some research beforehand, you can help them say things that will help you.

Comment: In the UK PhD system you are expected to commit to a supervisor and a topic way too early and you don't have time to explore various options. So what is happening to you is very normal. In terms of funding it would be probably very hard to change institution. So like Andy Putman suggested you need to talk to your supervisor. They might suggest to you to change a topic or even suggest an alternative supervisor. You should also try to think about options, preferably some area where you can still use some of the knowledge you have already acquired.

Comment: Actually in an ideal world this could have been a positive experience. You have learned what you don't like. Moreover, you might find out that what you have learned till now could be useful in future research in your new topic that maybe no-one else even thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can offer some wisdom on this.

I struggled in the first year of a PhD in computer science but I succeeded at the end and gained a scholarship. My second year, however, didn't improve despite making another breakthrough. At the end of that year the powers that be in my department agreed to giving me some time off in order to put my finances in order.

Subsequent to this they have also agreed, at least in principle, to let me take my PhD to the mathematics department, and possibly my scholarship with it. The reason for the move is that I have become increasingly interested in the formal verification of mathematics and have devoted all of my spare time to writing a proof assistant. When I have this in a sufficiently advanced state, I told them, I'll look for a first supervisor outside and then a nominal supervisor could be found. This was all somewhat hypothetical but there was a problem with this plan anyway: software takes a long time to write! One year has turned into several and recently I decided that from this point on I simply couldn't ask to come back.

I now for the wisdom: it really doesn't matter.

If I recall, Timothy Gowers wrote a year or so ago that mathematics is a calling. Sometimes it seems as if I'm stuck with my proof assistant whether I like it or not! Thoughts of an academic career are completely beside the point. I honestly can't see what being inside of academia would give me right now. Less of an income, probably. (joke)

So if you are cut out for some sort of mathematics, I reckon it will come to you in time. You may not be able to help yourself. But don't think that such a calling is necessarily tied to a career in academia, because I think that this is increasingly not the case, and probably never really was.

Comment: I'm not sure why your personal story is relevant for the question.